# How to add bootstrap to a custom plugin

Tags: wordpress

I need some help. I’m developing a plugin and I need to use Bootstrap on the shortcodes.
I download Bootstrap and upload it to my-plugin/public/css folder.
Then I create the function to load the styles, scripts and the shortcode.

```
private function define_public_hooks() {
$plugin_public = new My_Wp_Tools_Public( $this->get_plugin_name(), $this->get_version() );
$this->loader->add_action( ‘wp_enqueue_scripts’, $plugin_public, ‘enqueue_styles’ );
$this->loader->add_action( ‘wp_enqueue_scripts’, $plugin_public, ‘enqueue_scripts’ );
// Add a shortcode to home page.
$this->loader->add_action(‘mwpt-most-popular-today’, $plugin_public, ‘mwpt_most_popular_today’);
add_shortcode(‘mwpt-most-popular-today’, array( $plugin_public, ‘mwpt_most_popular_today’));
}
```

Here is the functions to load styles and scripts:

```
public function enqueue_styles() {
wp_register_style( ‘bootstrap-css’, plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . ‘css/bootstrap-4.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.full.css’, array(), ‘1.0.0’, all);
wp_enqueue_style(‘bootstrap-css’);
}
public function enqueue_scripts() {
wp_register_script(‘bootstrap-js’, plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . ‘css/bootstrap-4.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.full.js’, array(‘jquery’), ‘3.3.1’, true);
wp_enqueue_script(‘bootstrap-js’);
}
```

And the function to create a shortcode example using bootstrap:

```
function mwpt_most_popular_today($content) {
$html = ‘<br><div class=”alert alert-success”>Success! Indicates a successful or positive action.</div>’;
return $content . $html;
}
```

For some reason the bootstrap its not styling the $html variable, what I’m doing wrong?
Best regards.

Comment: you should look at [add_action documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/#user-contributed-notes). your `add_action()`'s should be: `add_action( ‘wp_enqueue_scripts’, array($plugin_public, ‘enqueue_scripts’) );`

Comment: @SamvelAleqsanyan the OP seems to be using [Devin Vinson's boilerplate](https://github.com/DevinVinson/WordPress-Plugin-Boilerplate) as a base to build his plugin. If so, then that's the right way to enqueue scrips and stylesheets (see [example code](https://github.com/DevinVinson/WordPress-Plugin-Boilerplate/blob/master/plugin-name/includes/class-plugin-name.php#L169-L176)).

Comment: Daniel, are the curly single quotes (`‘` and `’`) part of your actual code? Seems like a formatting issue.

Comment: @cabrerahector, yes, you're right. just the default wordpress function works not in such way, as you know

Comment: @cabrerahector here is the actual [code](https://gist.github.com/Dualcon/9db06bf8fb44384012dc1da4a4687b9e).
I can't find what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @DanielVieira [here](https://gist.github.com/Dualcon/9db06bf8fb44384012dc1da4a4687b9e#file-class-my-wp-tools-public-php-L68-L69) and [here](https://gist.github.com/Dualcon/9db06bf8fb44384012dc1da4a4687b9e#file-class-my-wp-tools-public-php-L98-L99) the code is commented out.

Comment: @DanielVieira where are your Bootstrap files located in your plugin structure?

Comment: Well, it was my fault. The bootstrap was always included but the html code that I used was not complete, thats why never worked.
Here is how to include the bootstrap css and js.
public function enqueue_styles() {
 wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-css', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'css/bootstrap-4.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css', array(), '1.0.0', 'all');
 }

 public function enqueue_scripts() {
 wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'css/bootstrap-4.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js', array(), '1.0.0', 'all');
 }
Thanks for help.